# Apps Script: Copy rows to another sheet without the headers/headlines

Tags: google-apps-script

**ISSUE:** 
 I have 2 identical sheets and want to copy **all non-empty rows from the first sheet to the second sheet**. And this copying process should start at row 2 of column A of the first sheet. In other words, I do NOT want to include the headers/headlines in the copy.

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:** 
 The script below copies the whole first sheet (including the headers/headline) instead of starting to copy at row 2. I am pretty sure I am missing something and won´t be able to find it out, as I am still learning how to deal with Apps Script.

**QUESTION:** 
 Can somebody please correct the code below, so that it can **copy** only the **non-empty rows** from the first sheet to the second sheet and **without the headers/headline**?

Thank you so much in advance.

```
function copyAndAddNewEntries() {

  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SOURCE_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('SOURCE_SHEET_NAME')
  var sourceSheetrange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var sourceSheetData = sourceSheetrange.getValues();
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('TARGET_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('TARGET_SHEET_NAME');

  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, sourceSheetrange.getHeight(), sourceSheetrange.getWidth()).setValues(sourceSheetData);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy the rows that all empty columns are not empty from the source sheet, and want to put the values to the destination sheet.
- You want to remove the header row from the source values.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function copyAndAddNewEntries() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SOURCE_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('SOURCE_SHEET_NAME');
  var sourceSheetrange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var [, ...sourceSheetData] = sourceSheetrange.getValues();
  sourceSheetData = sourceSheetData.filter(e => e.join("") != "");
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('TARGET_SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('TARGET_SHEET_NAME');
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, sourceSheetData.length, sourceSheetData[0].length).setValues(sourceSheetData);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Your code works exactly as intended. Thank you so much!!!! And if you allow me one last question: Is it possible to change your script in a way that I can include multiple SOURCE SHEETS and copy the content of ALL these multiple SOURCE SHEETS to the same TARGET SHEET? AGAIN: Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Bob Hardball Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, can I ask you about the detail of `multiple source sheets`? In this case, do you want to retrieve the multiple sheets in one Google Spreadsheet? Or, you want to retrieve the multiple sheets in each Spreadsheet? In this case, do you want to retrieve the values from one sheet for one Google Spreadsheet? I cannot understand your new question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I have 20 SOURCE SHEETS. I want to copy the contents of ALL these 20 SOURCE SHEETS and put them in ONE single TARGET SHEET. But with your current script, I can copy and put the content of only one sheet into the TARGET SHEET. So, is it possible to modify your script, so that I can copy the content of ALL the 20 TARGET SHEETS and put them into one single TARGET SHEET? Thank you so much in advance for helping me :)

Comment: @Bob Hardball Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `20 SOURCE SHEETS` of your new question. In this case, do you want to retrieve the multiple sheets in one Google Spreadsheet? Or, you want to retrieve the multiple sheets in each Spreadsheet? In this case, do you want to retrieve the values from one sheet for one Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: I want to do EXACTLY what you are asking for here: "do you want to retrieve the multiple sheets in one Google Spreadsheet?". In other words, yes, I want to retrieve the content of multiple sheets in one Google Spreadsheet. Thank you so much again for your help :)

Comment: @Bob Hardball Thank you for replying. From your replying, you want to retrieve the values from the multiple sheets in one Google Spreadsheet. In that case, do you want to retrieve the values from the sheet names? Or, you want to retrieve the values from all sheets from one Spreadsheet? I would like to think of your new question by correctly understanding it. I apologize for this.

Comment: I have created a question here with ALL the details you are asking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69662352/apps-script-copy-and-paste-rows-from-multiple-source-sheets-to-a-mastersheet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238398/discussion-between-bob-hardball-and-tanaike).

Comment: @Bob Hardball I checked your new question. And now, I answered it. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Tainaike - Thank you so much for getting back to me. I am currently checking the modified version of your script. I will get in touch, as soon as I am done. Thank you so much again :)

Comment: @Bob Hardball Thank you for replying. At that time, please comment it to your new question.

Comment: the last modified version of your script works, as long as ALL my source sheets are in the same spreadsheet. But all my sheets are not in the same spreadsheet. Is there anything we can do about it? I mean is it possible to also include sheets that are in different spreadsheets? And maybe we should continue the conversation in chat? Thanks :)

Comment: @Bob Hardball Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I commented `Thank you for replying. At that time, please comment it to your new question.` in my previous comment. If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.